# Python how to use "urlopen" open a fluid layout web page?

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen

I can use `urllib2.urlopen` to get a static web page context, but it can not open a fluid layout web page.

How can I get a fluid layout web page using `urlopen` or something else in Python?

Comment: What's a fluid layout web page? Exactly what kind of output are you expecting to get? text containing the html? A browser window that the user can interact with? Something else?

Comment: waterfall flow layout web site, I want get html content.

Comment: Sounds like you mean one of those trendy websites where you scroll down to the bottom and it shows a box saying "loading more..." and then another couple of pages of content appear where the end of the page used to be. I don't think there's an easy way to get all the content from that kind of page. Especially since some of those pages could serve literally an infinite amount of content.

Comment: You are right. Can you open this page ? http://i.youku.com/u/UMzE2OTY2NjUy/videos, default, I just get the section "【09高分局】尸王人马" in the end. I want get full.

Comment: You have to find ajax query which loads additional components for page and try to emulate it with urllib2.urlopen or you can try to use something like that http://docs.pyspider.org/en/latest/tutorial/Render-with-PhantomJS/

Comment: To get the contents of the next page, think as a browser. What prompts the browser to load more content? The answer is in the HTML, so your solution might be specific for the site you are trying to capture.